# How to create a simple DLL for a custom SQL Server extended stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, dll

I am using an older version of SQL Server (2000).  I do not want my users to have permission to run master.dbo.xp_cmdshell.  I am trying to create a custom DLL that I can use to create my own extended stored procedure that I grant users permission to run - one that is hard-coded to execute a specific batch file that users need to be able to run on demand.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to create the DLL.  Here is my header file stdafx.h:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef INDLL_H
    #define INDLL_H

    #ifdef EXPORTING_DLL
        extern __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld() ;
    #else
        extern __declspec(dllimport) void HelloWorld() ;
    #endif
#endif
```

and here is my main file dllmain.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define EXPORTING_DLL

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                   LPVOID lpReserved)
{ return TRUE; }

void HelloWorld() {
    system("f:\\bin\\batchfilename.bat");
}
```

When I try to debug this project, I see that the build succeeds, but I get an error "Unable to start program: <path to compiled dll>."  Do you think this DLL will work, and if so, how can I test it to see for myself if it works?

Comment: +1 for not letting users run xp_cmdshell

Comment: Here is a reference for coding DLLs for extended stored procedures in SQL Server 2000: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215790(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Another helpful [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/9IVmp2Em7tU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, After many hours of Googling, I successfully compiled a DLL to add as a SQL Server 2000 extended stored procedure.  I'm going to share it here, since it's just a compilation of things I've put together from my Googling.  (I used Visual Studio 2010).  I'm not going to post everything - I started by creating a new project in Visual Studio and choosing Win32 Console Application, then Next, then DLL.  It creates a few header files and other files for you.  Some of them I didn't see any need for.  And some of the header files you must add to the project manually.  But here's my main .cpp code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"         
#include "srv.h"   //Must get from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\DevTools\Include            
#include "shellapi.h"  //need for ShellExecute          
#include "string"   //needed for std:string         
#include <sys/stat.h>  //need for stat in fileExists function below         

#define DLL_FUNC extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)          

__declspec(dllexport) ULONG __GetXpVersion() {          
   return ODS_VERSION;          
}           

bool fileExists(const std::string& filename) {          
    struct stat buf;            
    if (stat(filename.c_str(), &buf) != -1)         
    { return true; }            
    return false;           
}           

DLL_FUNC int __stdcall RunPP() {            
    if (fileExists("C:\\FileOnServer\\execute.bat")) {      
        ShellExecute(NULL,TEXT("open"), TEXT("C:\\FileOnServer\\execute.bat"), NULL, NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);       
        return 0;   
    } else {        
        MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, TEXT("File not found."), TEXT("Message"), MB_OK);  
        return 1;   
    }       
}
```

I learned that you can test out this DLL using rundll32 (`rundll32 yourdllname.dll,functionname` {no space after comma}) from the command line, but only if you include a .def file in your project.  My def file is

```
LIBRARY
EXPORTS
RunPP
```

Also, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215790%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) states, I tried to add a reference to Opends60.lib in Project > Properties... > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, but it looks like it got removed at some point.

For those of you as newbie as I am, I had to learn a lot of things in the project's Property pages like switching C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library to /MD.  Also learning how to compile in Release mode, where to locate the resulting .dll file, etc.

Then when moving the compiled DLL to my SQL Server machine (Win2003R2), I had to install the VC++ 2010 Redistributable for it to run.  Then I copied the DLL to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Binn on my machine (same place where xp_cmdShell extended stored procedure's DLL was), and then ran sp_addextendedproc according to the documentation to register it as an available extended stored procedure in the master database.  Then granting privileges for users to execute it, etc.

I know all this is an old technology.  I should just upgrade my SQL Server version.  But maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

1. instead of 'running' the DDL, attach to a running process: sqlservr.exe. Set your break points, then load the XP. The debugger breakpoint will fire and you can step through the code.
2. change the project start option to [Start external program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68c8335t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and choose sqlservr.exe as the external program.

Both options require you to know what you're doing, specially the second one (eg. make sure service is stopped, specify instance name in startup args and have proper access to SQL data dirs).

Obviously the better option is to upgrade to SQL Server 2005 (At least) and use SQLCLR instead.